# How to create sparkmagic session automatically (without having to manually interact with widget user-interface)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter

I am using `sparkmagic` to connect Jupyter notebooks to a remote spark cluster via Livy.

The way it is now, I need to execute a notebook cell to bring up the `%manage_spark` user-interface widget, and manually select the language and click "create-session" in order to establish the spark context for the notebook.

[image]

**Is there a way to automatically generate the session when executing the cell, instead of having to manually select the language and hit "create-session"?**

Can one provide arguments to the `sparkmagic` somehow for instance?

I'm imagining being able to do Kernel->Restart & Run All, and have the notebook execute completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of late, but here is how I pass the parameters for the spark session in the cell

```
%spark add -s session -l python -t None -u http://localhost:8998
```

Comment: Been so long I don't have any way to test this in a reasonable amount of time. Looks like this could work. Figuring out how to point to Livy might take a minute, but this could work.

Comment: Is there any solution for notebook side? I'm trying to do the same thing, but by modifying the jupyter_notebook_config.py with `c.NotebookApp.nbserver_extensions = {"sparkmagic.magics": True}`. but it doens't work. I hope someone could continue exploring this issue.